# Adding specific node field content in panels

Tags: entities, panels

For a better understanding, I will try to explain my problem with a concrete example. I know that I probably should achieve this a different way but I've been working like this for a lot of websites I've made and it's the cleanest and effective way (at least for me) to do this.

- I have a content type which contains a few fields.
- I'm using a few mini-panels as a block to place contents from nodes of the content type mentioned above
- In those mini-panels, I often have to display only a specific field from a specific node

The problem is that when I click to add content in my pane and select "existing node", I'm only allowed to show the entire node content with a specific build mode.

All I want is to add a field content of a specific node I've created. Not the whole node.

At the moment, I have to use display suite and add a new display and then, only display the specific field in this newly created display and then finally add "existing node" / select the specific node / select the template I've created with display suite which contains only the one field...

It's very tedious ! Is there a way to only select one field ? Or do you have advice on how to achieve this ?

Thank you.